# How to configure Inbound Traffic Control ( TC ) between Docker Container & Host Machine

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, ubuntu, rabbitmq

Context:

I'm trying to simulate traffic drop between RabbitMQ Client ( Host ) running in host & RabbitMQ Server running in Docker Container.

I'm trying to check if RabbitMQ client ( consumer ) send ack to RabbitMQ Server ( container ) drops, what happens to that message in RabbitMQ server & what happens to RabbitMQ Client.

OS:

```
uname -a 
Linux saths 5.15.0-71-generic #78~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 19 11:26:48 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My Host Network Interfaces:

```
sudo tc qdisc show               
qdisc noqueue 0: dev lo root refcnt 2 
qdisc noqueue 0: dev wlp0s20f3 root refcnt 2 
qdisc fq_codel 0: dev vmnet1 root refcnt 2 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5.0ms interval 100.0ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn 
qdisc fq_codel 0: dev vmnet8 root refcnt 2 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5.0ms interval 100.0ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn
```

What i have tried already:
vmnet1

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev vmnet1 root netem loss random 50%

sudo tc qdisc show                                      
qdisc noqueue 0: dev lo root refcnt 2 
qdisc noqueue 0: dev wlp0s20f3 root refcnt 2 
qdisc netem 8003: dev vmnet1 root refcnt 2 limit 1000 loss 50%
qdisc fq_codel 0: dev vmnet8 root refcnt 2 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5.0ms interval 100.0ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn
```

vmnet8

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev vmnet root netem loss random 50%

sudo tc qdisc show                                      
qdisc noqueue 0: dev lo root refcnt 2 
qdisc noqueue 0: dev wlp0s20f3 root refcnt 2 
qdisc fq_codel 0: dev vmnet1 root refcnt 2 limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5.0ms interval 100.0ms memory_limit 32Mb ecn
qdisc netem 8003: dev vmnet8 root refcnt 2 limit 1000 loss 50%
```

I have applied both the settings above and tried executed the below producer & consumer code.

Producer:

```
const amqplib = require('amqplib');


const open = require('amqplib').connect('amqp://localhost');

const q = 'moon';
let i = 100;

open.then(function(conn) {
  return conn.createChannel();
}).then(function(ch) {
  return ch.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
    while (i > 0 && i < 10000) {
      console.log('Running ', i);
      ch.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from(i.toString())); 
      i = i + 100;
    }
  });
}).catch(console.warn);
```

Consumer:

```
const amqplib = require('amqplib');


const open = require('amqplib').connect('amqp://localhost');

const q = 'moon';

open.then(function(conn) {
  return conn.createChannel();
}).then(function(ch) {
  return ch.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
    return ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
      if (msg !== null) {
        console.log('Consumed New Message', msg.content.toString());
        ch.ack(msg);
        console.log('Message acked', msg.content.toString());
      }
    });
  });
}).catch(console.warn);
```

Docker Compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
```

But after executing both producer & consumer scripts, none of message produced & consumer messages got dropped.

Most of the examples i'm seeing is to configure `tc` for outbound traffic, but in this case i believe i have to control inbound traffic in container. How to achieve this ?